# Autowiring using <context:annotation-config/>

Tags: spring

I am using Field Injection

1)Case 1 : If I am using

```
  context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-config.xml","test-infrastructure-config.xml");
```

And not using context:annotation-config , things dont work as expected

2) Case 2 : If am Using

```
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MainConfig.class);    (NO @EnableAutoConfiguration)
```

And MainConfig Class looks like :

```
    @Configuration
    @ImportResource({"classpath:application-config.xml","classpath:test-infrastructure-config.xml"})
   public class MainConfig {

   }
```

And not using context:annotation-config , things WORK with field injection

3)And if I am using Java configuration , i dont need to use @AnnotationDrivenConfig irrespective of how I create
Application Context

Can someone please help me to understand the behaviour?

Comment: When using XML configuration it is assumed that you manually wire all the beans (from a historical perspective). If you want to use annotation driven processing you need to enable this with `<context:annotation-config />` (and it is also turned on when using `<context:component-scan />`. When using Java based configured it is assumed that you have all your wiring information in java classes and hence annotation processing is enabled by default. (Basically case 2 and 3 are the same).

Comment: In Case 2 , I am using XML configuration only , I have @ImportResource({"classpath:application-config.xml","classpath:test-infrastructure-config.xml"}) above MainConfig...I will update my question

Comment: In case 2 you aren't using XML only... The `@ImportResource` is an indication that you are mixing Java and XML and the fact that you are using Spring Boot makes it Java Config first and thus has all the annotation processing enabled.